# Highlight words in text

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm trying to select a single word, then apply something to it. Example as below.

```
<p>Some text here</p>
```

Is there a way to select the word **text**, then apply something to it? For example **.css()**  - I know you can select the whole text, then select word number 2, but that's not what I'm trying to do. The word could be many places.

Comment: Can't you use either the classname or id with p tag? that will solve your problem.

Comment: Not an answer, so I'll comment: Tim Down's [`Rangy`](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) is useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: @jsp: No it wouldn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how would that work? Could you show me an example as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the target Element and its children, filter their `contents` and search for a textual nodeType:

```js
var word = 'text';

var rgx = new RegExp('\\b('+word+')\\b', 'ig');

$('p, p *').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(rgx, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some text and a link <a href="text.html">text.html</a> here and <b>some bold text there</b>. Text Is Uppercase.<br>Text... text.<br>  Textual.</p>
```

I believe the above should be quite promising since it'll not crash the HTML since it doesn't matches attributes strings.

Answer (score -1):

You can't select a word, as it is not an element.

To make it possible, you will have to wrap your words in spans.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "select." You can certainly get a `Range` for it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder perhaps, but if you want to style it, the wrapping is unavoidable.

Comment: @ MightyPork: Sure, but once you have a range, you can do that dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding; you want to play with a single word in in a sentence.

```html
<p>This a <span style="color:blue">sample</span> paragraph.</p>
```