# Change a specific word's css across the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I want to change a specific word's css through out the site.I can't add any html element around that word (like span,div) because that word is using several times and many places on site.

Is it possible to change this by css?

Comment: Take a look at this http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx

Comment: Yes, and there are some duplicates of this question already, I'm sure. EDIT - if you only want CSS, though, why use the JS tag?

Comment: i didn't find any question

Comment: *"I can't add any html element around that word (like span,div) because that word is using several times and many places on site."* And? This is where global search-and-replace comes in handy, whether in an IDE, using `sed`, etc.

Comment: @Jan.J i'm really interested to find out how that pen can solve the problem at hand. It uses selectors like `nth-letter`, in a website how do could you find out the position a particular word using those..??

Comment: It is only possible with JS help http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bHAGs

Comment: do you have it inside any particular container?

Comment: That script wraps all words/letters etc. with special spans, and adds specific css styles to site.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this purely with CSS. So your options are:

1. What you said you "couldn't" do — edit the source files, e.g., global search and replace. Put a span with a relevant class around the word and style that class.
2. Use JavaScript to retroactively wrap the word in an element (a `span` would probably be best), again use a class on it and style that class.

If you use jQuery, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622163/157247) helps you easily wrap specific words with a span. If you don't, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158204/157247) shows how to do it.

Comment: i can't edit source file because i really don't know how many times that word appearing

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal: That doesn't make any sense. You *find out* how many times, using (again) a global search and replace. Global search (and the variant, global search and replace) is an absolutely *fundamental* tool of programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fraid a pure CSS solution will not work for you. I can only offer a JavaScript solution that will wrap the target words in a tag for you.

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkXp2/1/)

```
var styleWord = function(target, word)
{
    var html = target.innerHTML;
    html = html.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"), '<span class="styled">'+word+'</span>');
    target.innerHTML = html;
};
```

The function I wrote takes in two params: the target element wherein you want the words changed (it won't leave HTML tags and attributes alone, so you might want to refine it) and the word you're looking for. It will wrap the word in a `span` so you can style it any way you wish.

Comment: Beware that this will completely wipe out event handlers on descendant elements if they're hooked up prior to your doing the replacement.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it will. This is a dumb one-liner that's meant to be written in a more fool-proof way. I'm not up to writing a complete JS plugin at the moment, I'm afraid :). And thanks for the sencond comment; indeed, I accidentally removed the var declaration.